# Read information of ID causing error from Exception

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, exception

In C# My Sql Entity Framework 6 Insert is return exception

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
> (`portaldb`.`masterselectionhistory`, CONSTRAINT
> `FK_MasterSelectionHistory_Contacts_MasterId` FOREIGN KEY (`MasterId`)
> REFERENCES `masters` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

The exception is occuring while trying to insert a List of records to the db

```
try{
    List<int> masterIds =  // around 20k ID exists 
                    foreach (int id in masterIds)
                    {
                        //Add Selection History to record against the contact!
                        #region insert to ContactSelectionHistory 
                        MasterSelectionHistory dbEntry = new MasterSelectionHistory();
                        dbEntry.MasterId = id;
                        dbEntry.SelectionId = --;
                        dbEntry.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
                        dbEntry.CreatedBy = ---;
                        context.MasterSelectionHistory.Add(dbEntry);
                        #endregion
                    }  
    
                    //Save all the db context changes
                    await context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);  //EXception is throwing from here
 }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                   //Can read ID causing error from ex object ?
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(ex.Message);
                }
```

Is there any way to know which among the ID is causing the issue from exception object

Comment: I would add another try/catch in the foreach loop that way the catch section of code can access the id variable as well.

Comment: context.SaveChangesAsync(). is outside the loop Means Saving all entries together. Save 1 by 1 is expensive operation as the list is huge

Comment: Oops hadnt seen the SaveChangesAsync ,my bad i would then go about writing it this way , as i loop through the huge list I check the masters table for ids that already exist and those i will add to a final list that I will bulkinsert in my destination table. SaveChanges is inefficient for such huge inserts i prefer to use this package that i find easy [BulkInsert](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.EFCore/)